# Error using python and sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a directory (/home/usuario/Desktop/Example) with one database (MyBBDD.db) and the file (script.py) that run the command "UPDATE". 
If in the terminal I'm in the directory "Example", script.py work fine but if Im not in the directory "Example" and I execute script.py like this:
"`python /home/usuario/Desktop/Example/script.py`" doesnt work fine, the error is: "no such table: name_table".
Somebody know what is the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

---

code as of comments *script.py*

```
import urllib
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('MyBBDD.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute ("UPDATE...")
conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Please show us the code from script.py. Are you using a relative or absolute path in that file?

Comment: elethan thanks for reply me so fast. script.py is like this: 
import urllib
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('MyBBDD.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute ("UPDATE...")

conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a connection object with `sqlite3` in script.py, use the absolute file path, i.e.

```
con = sqlite3.connect('/home/usuario/Desktop/Example/MyBBDD.db')
```

Comment: Yes! Wok fine!! Thanks you very much :)